# Want to get sum till date for past 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is the code I wrote to get the records

```
SELECT run_time, SUM(rec_cnt) reg_cnt FROM(
select run_time,rec_cnt from
(select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LST_UPDT_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') run_time,max(Running_Total) rec_cnt from (
SELECT
    LST_UPDT_TIME,
    (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM DM_REG_SMRY T2
     WHERE T2.LST_UPDT_TIME <= T1.LST_UPDT_TIME AND REG_STS_ID = 14
    ) AS Running_Total
FROM
    DM_REG_SMRY T1
    order by T1.LST_UPDT_TIME
    )
    group by TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LST_UPDT_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
    order by TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LST_UPDT_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
    )
    UNION
(SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE+1 - ROWNUM) run_time , 0 as rec_cnt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 30)
)GROUP BY run_time
ORDER BY run_time;
```

I got following output

```
18-06-2015 00:00    6
19-06-2015 00:00    7
20-06-2015 00:00    0
21-06-2015 00:00    0
22-06-2015 00:00    0
23-06-2015 00:00    0
24-06-2015 00:00    12
25-06-2015 00:00    0
26-06-2015 00:00    0
27-06-2015 00:00    0
28-06-2015 00:00    0
29-06-2015 00:00    0
30-06-2015 00:00    0
01-07-2015 00:00    0
02-07-2015 00:00    0
03-07-2015 00:00    49
04-07-2015 00:00    0
05-07-2015 00:00    0
06-07-2015 00:00    0
07-07-2015 00:00    0
08-07-2015 00:00    0
09-07-2015 00:00    0
10-07-2015 00:00    49
11-07-2015 00:00    0
12-07-2015 00:00    0
13-07-2015 00:00    65
14-07-2015 00:00    77
15-07-2015 00:00    101
16-07-2015 00:00    0
17-07-2015 00:00    0
```

But I want the last non zero value to be repeated for the zero place

Please help

Comment: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LST_UPDT_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')` is totally senseless if `LST_UPDT_TIME` is a `DATE` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of rows in `DM_REG_SMRY` accumulated in the past 30 days (starting with `SYSDATE-(30-1)` and ending with today `SYSDATE-(1-1)`) and with `REG_STS_ID=14`. And you want to get the accumulated count by date.

This means that if you have on `DM_REG_SMRY` (with `REG_STS_ID=14`):

```
 6 rows on 18-06-2015
 1 row  on 19-06-2015 
 5 rows on 24-06-2015 
37 rows on 03-07-2016
16 rows on 13-07-2015 
12 rows on 14-07-2015
24 rows on 15-07-2015
```

you really want this result:

```
18-06-2015 00:00    6
19-06-2015 00:00    7
20-06-2015 00:00    7
21-06-2015 00:00    7
22-06-2015 00:00    7
23-06-2015 00:00    7
24-06-2015 00:00    12
25-06-2015 00:00    12
26-06-2015 00:00    12
27-06-2015 00:00    12
28-06-2015 00:00    12
29-06-2015 00:00    12
30-06-2015 00:00    12
01-07-2015 00:00    12
02-07-2015 00:00    12
03-07-2015 00:00    49
04-07-2015 00:00    49
05-07-2015 00:00    49
06-07-2015 00:00    49
07-07-2015 00:00    49
08-07-2015 00:00    49
09-07-2015 00:00    49
10-07-2015 00:00    49
11-07-2015 00:00    49
12-07-2015 00:00    49
13-07-2015 00:00    65
14-07-2015 00:00    77
15-07-2015 00:00    101
16-07-2015 00:00    101
17-07-2015 00:00    101
```

If this is what you really want then a possible solution is:

```
SELECT runtime, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM DM_REG_SMRY 
           WHERE LST_UPDT_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - (30-1)) 
             AND LST_UPDT_TIME <  (runtime+1)
             AND REG_STS_ID = 14
      ) reg_cnt
  FROM 
      (
      SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - (LEVEL - 1)) runtime 
        FROM DUAL 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
      ) dates
  ORDER BY runtime;
```